# g++ inline assembly mismatch in brackets

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, g++, inline-assembly

g++ is complaining to me about a missing bracket in the following code:

```
                                              1                   2 3
                                              v                   v v
__asm__ volatile("inb %1, %0" : : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber) );
                ^                      ^               ^
                1                      2               3
```

as you can see the brackets are matching and there are three open brackets and three close brackets.

also for more information i am following a youtube tutorial

Comment: Output operands (`"=a"(result)`) should be between the first 2 colons and the input operands (`"Nd"(portnumber)`) should be after the second colon. Try `__asm__ volatile("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber) );`

Comment: I'd be curious which Youtube video it was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have an extra `:` before the output**, so you ended up with your output declaration in the input part.  **And the reason for that error: your input operand declaration where the compiler expects the clobber list.**  The clobber list can only include string literals (register names and `"memory"` and/or `"cc"`<sup>1</sup>), not `()`.

```
    __asm__ volatile("inb %1, %0" 
            : "=a" (result)       // output
            : "Nd" (portnumber)   // input
          //  : "memory"   // optional, clobber list
     );
```

You might want a `"memory"` clobber list to make sure this is ordered wrt. memory accesses.  Or not, if you're sure it doesn't need to be.

Footnote 1: asm statements on x86 implicitly clobber the condition codes, `"cc"`.  You can use it for documentation if you like.  But you don't want it here because `inb` doesn't touch EFLAGS.